# Listen to changes on childs with keys within specific range only?

Tags: javascript, firebase

I want to listen for changes on my `calendar`node, but only if they occur on a child that has a key between a specified interval.
My Firebase looks like this:

```
{
  "calendar":{
    "160622" : {
      // data
    },
    "160623" : {
      // data
    },
    "160624" : {
      // data
    },
    "160625" : {
      // data
    },
    "160626" : {
      // data
    },
    "160627" : {
      // data
    },
    ...
  },
  // other data
}
```

I want to do something equivalent to this:

```
firebaseRef.child("calendar").child("160622" to "160624").on("value", function(snapshot){
  // do stuff
});
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using [orderByKey()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#orderByKey) with [startAt()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#startAt) and [endAt()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#endtAt)?

```
firebaseRef.child("calendar").orderByKey().startAt("160622").endAt(160624").on("value", function(snapshot){
   // do stuff
});
```

Comment: Happy to help :) Thanks for upvoting